# Shell script I made is ridiculously verbose, and also is probably inefficient. Help!

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup

I am new to Ubuntu, and so far have done several things I am quite proud of:

Made an apache webserver with my own html (before a week ago I had never touched it)
Made a stratum mining server +titcoin node

And my latest project is making a shell script to backup my ENTIRE (that’s right) hard drive to a huge external one. Getting to the point, I know there’s quite a bit I could improve on (like the fact that it tells you the contents of everything it tars?), and I would like your opinion on it:

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -n1 -p “Would you like to back up your system? Uno for Si, and Dos for No.” 
echo
case $input in
1) fdisk -l;
echo;
read -p “Please enter the name of your backup disk that was displayed in the fdisk window: ” disk ;
echo;
echo “Backups now in progress! Please be aware that backups are saved to a Backups directory which this script creates, and backups are tarred and labelled by date!”;
echo “THIS WILL TAKE A VERY VERY LONG TIME IF YOU HAVE A LARGE FILESYSTEM! PLEASE BE PATIENT!!!”;
cd /;
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cp $(date +%Y%m%d).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp $(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups;
echo “Okay, all done! To restore your system, you will have to untar and manually do it yourself. If you have any issues, email name@example.com!”;; 
2) echo “Then why are you running this script?”;;
*) echo “I'm sorry, but I can’t do that…”

esac
```

Honestly, I have no idea what I am doing. Any suggestions?  Here is an excerpt from the output that has been going for around ~3 hours...
Well actually, the text is moving so fast I can't even copy/paste it...
[image]

Comment: I said this already in my answer, but just in case you're not going to read it: never ever leave your email address around the web, because spammers are going to scrape it. I removed it already from both your question and your answer, and I asked a moderator to remove it from the posts' revision histories.

Comment: What are titcoins? They sound fun!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global issues:

- **Use indentation**. It makes your code more readable (for you and for us).
- **Use only straight quotes in bash**. Other types of quotes might break commands.
- **Do not append `;` at the end of a single command**. The `;` character has a specific meaning and it's useless if appended to a single command.

Specific issues:

```
fdisk -l;
```

You need to run `fdisk` as `sudo`: `sudo fdisk -l`

```
read -n1 -p “Would you like to back up your system? Uno for Si, and Dos for No.”
```

You're not storing this input anywhere. Seeing the code below, you're missing `input` at the end (mind the space after the double-quotes): `read -n1 -p "Would you like to back up your system? Uno for Si, and Dos for No." input`

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cp $(date +%Y%m%d).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp $(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups;
```

The `tar` command is missing a `-f` option: without it `tar` outputs to `stdout` and not to the specified file; also the filename should be `$(date +%Y%m%d-%H)` to match the filename expected from `cp`: `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cpf $(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp $(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups;`

Final note: doing so, you're leaving all the backups in `/`, but you're also excluding a `/backups/` directory from the backup, so it seems like your goal is to store a copy of each backup in such folder. Make sure that such folder exists. The corrected version of the last command according to this is:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cpf backups/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp backups/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups;
```

So the indented, straight-quoted, useless-`;`-free, fixed version of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -n1 -p "Would you like to back up your system? Uno for Si, and Dos for No." input
echo
case $input in
    1)
        sudo fdisk -l
        echo
        read -p "Please enter the name of your backup disk that was displayed in the fdisk window: " disk
        echo
        echo "Backups now in progress! Please be aware that backups are saved to a Backups directory which this script creates, and backups are tarred and labelled by date!"
        echo "THIS WILL TAKE A VERY VERY LONG TIME IF YOU HAVE A LARGE FILESYSTEM! PLEASE BE PATIENT!!!"
        cd /
        sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cpf backups/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp backups/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups;
        echo "Okay, all done! To restore your system, you will have to untar and manually do it yourself. If you have any issues, email name@example.com!"
        ;;
    2)
        echo "Then why are you running this script?"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "I'm sorry, but I can’t do that…"
        ;;
esac
```

Last thing: **Never ever leave your email address around the web**. Spammers will scrape it. I have replaced it with `name@example.com` in my answer, in your answer and in your question.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Like I said, this is my first time writing any sort of script, and I literally had no knowledge of any commands at all, nor syntax. I saw a random shell script on the web, noticed his use of the commands, and learned from that tiny bit. Thanks a ton! Also, formatting went wonky. I had indentation.

Comment: Now I get a ./backup.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `)' with the corrections made above to the script below.

Comment: @Harm If you *really* need to use the script in your answer, update your question including the updated version of the script, otherwise I'm throwing rocks in the dark. But to be honest, your script is a bit messy. You should try to keep it simple when you can. If you update your question with the updated script, drop me a comment here so I can be notified.

Comment: Apologies. Edited

Comment: @Harm This is my fault, I forgot to readd the double semicolons at the end of the case statements, add them to your code and it should be fine. Also if you found that this answer solved your problem or it was the most useful to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the mark under the upvotes count

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a dream now! Also, this was my first stack exchange post, so I totally didn't know about the email thing.

Comment: @Harm This is general, works also for forums: if you place your email address visible, whoever is scraping that particular site is going to store it in no time. Then welcome to the site, also when you'll have more reputation consider upvoting answers (even to other's questions) and questions that you find useful and well written, the usual practice here is to upvote and to accept the answer that helped you the most in finding a solution to your problem (as well as to upvote other answers that you found useful regardless)

Comment: Super thorough, friendly and useful answer @kos that tick didn't come cheap!

Comment: @Arronical Thanks! No, indeed it didn't :)

Answer (score -1):

Alright, got it.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -n1 -p "Would you like to back up verbosely and with minimal directories?? Uno for Si, and Dos for No." input
echo
case $input in
1) fdisk -l
echo
cd /
mkdir TempBackup && cd TempBackup
read -p "Please enter the name of your backup disk that was displayed in the fdisk window: " disk 
echo
echo "Tarring your /etc/ folder, be patient!" && sudo tar -cpf etc.tar /etc && echo "etc is tarred, copying now!" && sudo cp etc.tar /mnt/$disk/Backups && echo "Tarring your /bin/ folder!" && sudo tar -cpf bin.tar /bin && echo "bin is tarred, copying now!" && sudo cp bin.tar /mnt/$disk/Backups && echo "Tarring your /home/ folder, if you use bitcoind or litecoind it will be a bit!" && sudo tar -cpf home.tar --exclude=.cache --exclude=.gvfs /home && echo "home is tarred, copying now!" && sudo cp home.tar /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cpf var.tar /var && echo "var is tarred, copying now!" && sudo cp etc.tar /mnt/$disk/Backups && cd / && echo "Tarring usr, IT IS UNLIKELY THAT THIS FILE CAN BE COPIED ON A FAT32 FS!!! AUTOSPLIT HAS BEEN ACTIVATED!!!" && sudo tar -cpf usr.tar /usr && echo "usr is tarred, copying/splitting now!" && mkdir split-files && cd split-files && split --bytes=1G /usr.tar split.tar && sudo cp * /mnt/$disk/Backups && cat split*.tar > usr.tar && cd /TempBackup && echo "Okay, finished! Let me clean up..."  && sleep 5 && echo "Cleaning all files...." && sudo rm -rf *.tar && echo "All Done!"
2) fdisk -l
echo
cd /
mkdir TempBackup && cd TempBackup
read -p "Please enter the name of your backup disk that was displayed in the fdisk window: " disk 
echo
echo "Backups now in progress! Please be aware that backups are saved to a Backups directory which this script creates, and backups are tarred and labelled by date!"
echo "THIS WILL TAKE A VERY VERY LONG TIME IF YOU HAVE A LARGE FILESYSTEM! PLEASE BE PATIENT!!!"
echo "THIS IS NOT THE SAME AS THE VERBOSE MODE! THIS COPIES ALL FILES TO DISK, NOT JUST THE COMMON ONES! YOU STILL HAVE TIME TO QUIT!!!"
sleep 10
cd /;
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk && sudo mount /dev/$disk /mnt/$disk && sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$disk/Backups && sudo tar -cpf $(date +%Y%m%d).tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev pts --exclude=backups . && sudo cp $(date +%Y%m%d-%H).tar /mnt/$disk/Backups
echo "Okay, all done! To restore your system, you will have to untar and manually do it yourself. If you have any issues, email name@example.com!"
*) echo "I'm sorry, but I can't do that..."
esac
```

Feel free to use this!

Comment: Use indentation, for ****'s sake. ANd your script is still syntactically invalid, since none of the case labels are ended by `;;`.

Comment: As I said before, indentation was implemented but I lost all formatting copying the code.